# Django python 3 " python: can't open file 'manage.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory"

Tags: django

I have installed only python 3 and django latest version but still this error is coming

> python: can't open file 'manage.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory.

Comment: What command you are running?

Comment: try changing you directory to where your manage.py file is.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you run your ./manage.py runserver in the same directory where manage.py file exists